# Where can I find a good open source user account management class/library in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, user-controls

I am looking for a good framework for user and user group management in PHP. I want a to be able to add/edit/delete profile, save in a db; add/edit/delete groups; assign a user as group leader, nothing more.

I tried http://www.phpclasses.org. There are many options there but I simply don't know which once to go for. I don't have much time to download each one to try out so I am wondering if anyone has come across anything good and useful. Preferably free but I don't mind paying or donating.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered PHP GACL?
http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

Check out http://usercake.com/ as well

Comment: easy for use, easy to install. I recommend it

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best one I found that goes into details as to whats going on

[http://www.evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features](http://evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features)